# SdCard is not usable with KitKat?

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, sd-card, app2sd

I am using **App Backup & Restore** for creating backup of my apps but with **KitKat** its using the internal **SdCard** as Storage.

When I explicitly set the external **SdCard** path it gives the error that it is unable to create folder,

I have also tried with creating folder under **android/data/[packagename]/files/** but it is still not able to do the same.

Is there any solution so that apps can use external storage for writing files.

**Note : I don't want to ROOT my Phone.**

Comment: This is a system level restriction therefore the only way to remove it is through use of root. Is there a reason you can't root?

Answer (score 2):

On my S4 Mini I configured the path as:

```
/storage/extSdCard/Android/data/mobi.infolife.appbackup/APP_Backup_Restore
```

and it works fine - device is not rooted.

Probably the first part (`/storage/extSdCard`) is different from device to device and maybe the path is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called SDFix on the Play store, but you will need root to run this. Running that should let you write to external SD cards again.
[Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.sdfix&hl=en):

Answer (score -3):

FAT32 SD cards don't work. Format the card to NTFS

Comment: Care to give some more details on why fat32 does not work? Also, why would NTFS work? NTFS is proprietary format and requires licensed drivers from Microsoft, can you cite where all devices with KitKat have this driver? AFAIK, officially, only some Samsung devices come with NTFS support, and that is because Samsung paid Microsoft to include support.

Comment: @Ryan That is true but for some reason, when i had a problem with my htc, the service center told me to format to ntfs and a friend of mine was told the same thing for a note 2 and lg g3